# What is the run-time to insert a string into a hash table?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, big-o, hashtable

I believe inserting into a hash table is average-case O(1) and worst-case O(n). So if we loop through a string and add each word to a hash table (which maps the word to the number of times it occurs in the string), wouldn't that be worst-case O(n^2) run-time? I tried to ask this before, but the answers said it was worst-case O(n). Thanks!

Comment: Inserting a *string* into a hash-table takes `O(|s|)` average time, where `|s|` is the length of the string. That's the cost of computing the hash, and even if you cache the hash for each string and amortize its cost over a lot of insertions, you still have to pay `O(|s|)` to find out that the string you just looked up is the one in the table (by comparing every character). So it's only O(1) if the string has a single character, in which case a hash table might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that under reasonable assumptions, a hash table will insert elements in O(1) average time and O(n) worse case time.

As for your problem, assuming you have n words in a string, you would have to iterate over each word and enter it into the hash table which would take O(n) average time or O(n^2) worst case time.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case of insert depends on how the implementation of insert function handles collisions and resolution techniques. This will have a greater influence in both put() and get() operations. The collision resolution techniques are implemented differently in each libraries. The core idea is to maintain all colliding keys in the same bucket. And during retrieval traverse all the colliding keys and apply some equality check to retrieve the given key. Important thing to note is we need to maintain both 'keys' and 'values' in the bucket, to facilitate the above mentioned equality check.

Another thing to consider is, during insertion operation a hashcode will be generated for the given key. We can consider this to be constant O(1) for every key.

In worst case, all the keys could fall in the same bucket and hence **O(n) for  1 get().** But for put() operation it is always constant **O(1)** irrespective of the collision.

Maintaining the list of colliding is a key factor. Some implementation​s are doing with BST rather than a linked list. Hence, worst case is O(log N) for insertion and retrieval.

At any cost, **O(N log N) could be the runtime of inserting N elements not O(N^2).**

Any decent implementation has to ensure the minimum colliding hash code of objects being generated, to have better performance.